# Given one column value return another column value based on some conditional

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

Input:

```
ColumnA:
A
A
B
B
C
C
```

Output

```
ColumnB:
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

The condition is: The column B will be 0 if the value in column A is the first time appear. Otherwise the column B will be 1. Thanks! Using pandas in Python.

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Comment: df.apply(lambda x: int(x.ColumnA in df.iloc[:x.name,0].tolist()), axis=1)  Tried this one. But the efficiency is not so good when there is a large data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) mask to `int`:

```
print (df.duplicated())
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool

df['ColumnB'] = df.duplicated().astype(int)
print (df)
  ColumnA  ColumnB
0       A        0
1       A        1
2       A        1
3       B        0
4       B        1
5       C        0
6       C        1
```

Comment: Your way is very efficient during processing the large data.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'C'}})

df
Out[284]: 
  ColumnA
0       A
1       A
2       B
3       B
4       C
5       C
```

Use an apply to check if the value has appeared before.

```
df['ColumnB'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x.ColumnA in df.iloc[:x.name,0].tolist()), axis=1)

df
Out[287]: 
  ColumnA  ColumnB
0       A        0
1       A        1
2       B        0
3       B        1
4       C        0
5       C        1
```

Comment: df.iloc[:x.name,1] ??

Comment: Do we have more faster way to get the results if there is a large data?